# Specific jQuery Code Not Working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am testing a webpage I have developed, and I have several jQuery scripts running in this webpage.

The webpage displays and functions as expected in Chrome and Firefox, but I am currently testing this in Internet Explorer (version 9).

All the other jQuery scripts are working on this page, except the following script:

```
$(".SpecificTextboxClass").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 3) {
        $(".SpecificTextboxClass").not(this).val(0);}});
```

**UPDATE EDIT:**

Here is the code for the textbox:

```
<input type="text" name="scale" class="Validation SpecificTextboxClass" value="1">
```

Could the double class be causing the problem?

**SECOND UPDATE:**

I just loaded the webpage in Internet Explorer 6 and had the same problem.  I am also using jQuery 1.9.1 (as fas as I know).

**THIRD UPDATE:**

The problem seems to resolve itself when the validation code is removed:

```
$('.Validation').keyup(function () {
    if ("" != this.value.replace(/([0-9]|10)(\.\d{1,3})?]/g, '')) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '').substring(0,5);}});
```

Comment: try to find out the specific line.Then it is easy

Comment: typo SpecificTextboxClas

Comment: Any errors in IE console

Comment: No errors - page loads correctly and runs all other jQuery scripts on the page.

Comment: Ok, it has something to do with the code - as I swapped the two classes around, and the validation jQuery script still works, but the script above does not.

Comment: that code looks pretty innocuous. I can't see why it wouldn't work. Have you tried making a jsFiddle or similar to test it in isolation from the rest of your code?

Comment: Fiddle as requested: http://jsfiddle.net/hkhUQ/5/

Comment: Fiddle works fine on IE7/IE8...

Comment: Good point - but then it does not work when the same code is applied to my webpage....

Comment: Something else must be generating an error that is keeping that piece of code from compiling/running...

Comment: @bastos.sergio I just updated the original post.

Comment: Re the update: Hmm... that makes it more interesting. Perhaps an updated fiddle that contains both event handlers would be in order. I'd also suggest trying to debug it by putting some `console.log` messages around the code. I suspect the events are interfering with each other; I can't see why they would at first glance, but seeing what sequence things are happening and what value the field has when each event is called might help you debug. (NB: use `console.log()` not `alert()` for this because `alert()` will alter the results)

Comment: @Spudley Here's the updated fiddle with the validation code: http://jsfiddle.net/hkhUQ/8/

Comment: @DustinCook - You've turned both regexes into `match`; I only meant to do that to the first one. The `match()` should be on the `if()` line, since that line is supposed to do a pattern match. The other line should be left as `.replace()` (and the pattern left as it was), since it is intended to do string replacement.

Comment: Thanks @Spudley - I think I confused myself, tested it again and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, thanks to your jsFiddle, I think I've found the problem.

The bug is in your validation code, in the regex pattern you're using to test whether it's valid -- you have a stray `]` character at the end of the pattern.

```
if ("" != this.value.replace(/([0-9]|10)(\.\d{1,3})?]/g, '')) {
                                                    ^
                                              this is invalid
```

This is making the test fail every time, which in turn is causing it to change the value in code, which in turn appears to be stopping the change event from firing.

You can fix the problem by removing the rogue `]` character.

I'd also suggest using regex `.match()` rather than `.replace()` for the test -- `replace` is the wrong function for an `if()` test like that.

You could replace it directly with this:

```
if (!this.value.match(/^(([0-9]|10)(\.\d{1,3})?)*$/)) {
```

That will have exactly the same functionality but will be a lot more efficient to run.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hkhUQ/9/) for an update to your jsFiddle to demonstrate the fix. (note that it has `console.log()` calls in it, so make sure you have F12 dev tools open when you run it in IE)

However even then, I'm not convinced it's excatly what you want. This will (as will your previous version) return valid for strings like `3.1346.21710.45` -- ie multiple values concatenated together. In your `replace` version, this is caused by the `g` modifier (which replaces multiple occurrences). In my version, it's done by the `*` at the end of the patten.

If you only want a single value, remove the `g` from your version, or replace the `*` with a `?` in mine.

Finally, since it looks like you're just testing for a decimal value, you might also consider just using `parseFloat()` instead of all that regex.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That is awesome!  Thank you.  One thing - since the update the validation code restricted the entry to five characters - but this is not working... but it did with the previous code.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @DustinCook - that would be because it was failing the validation for everything, so the replace/substring was always being run. To fix the `if()` test use the `match()` variant in the answer, and as mentioned further down the answer, change the `*` at the end of it to a `?`.

Comment: The validation should restrict to only allow up to 3 decimal places and no text input.  Can you help with the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hkhUQ/11 - now the validation is not working at all!

Answer (score 0):

Check your "SpecificTextboxClass" input type, may be you have not added.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you didn't set up your code to run on document ready/window load.  You could be running into a race condition where your code runs before the DOM has had a chance to setup.

Please confirm that you are setting up your code like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(".TAB1val1").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 3) {
            $(".TAB1val1").not(this).val(0);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to alter your JQuery code then... IE is one of the slowest browsers around. Your code is probably running before the DOM has a chance to set up the html elements on the page...

Comment: So do I have to place that around each jQuery script?  Or can I use it once and put all the code inside it?

Comment: You can do it both ways really...  There's not limit to how many document ready events you can set on a page.  Although my personal preference is to put everything on a single document ready (it's useful when I quickly need to look up at what is running in the load event--if the code is distributed across several document ready events then I need to find then all on the page.)

Comment: Could I move one of the classes into a `<div>` tag to try and let it work?